# ffmpeg : error when added scale

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode batch mkv videos which will give a output with a watermark in it.

But when I add the `-vf 840:480` or other resolution (like **720p** or **1080p**),
it don't run but without `-vf scale` it works fine but I need to set resolution for the video.

**Without -vf**

```
for %%I in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -map 0 -vf scale=840:480 -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy "480\%%~nI.mkv"
```

**With -vf**

```
for %%I in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -map 0 -vf scale=840:480 -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy "480\%%~nI.mkv"
```

Please help me with how to run the command with `-vf scale`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for %%I in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)',scale=840:480[v]" -map [v] -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 -codec:a copy "480\%%~nI.mkv"
```

All filters acting upon a stream should be within the same filtergraph.

Comment: `for %%I in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i a.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)',scale=840:480[v]" -map 0 -codec:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 18 "Temp480\%%~nI.mkv"`  I tried to change the code and tried to us this but id didn't worked

Comment: You need to add `-map [v]` and change `-map 0` to `-map 0:a`

Comment: thanks mana... can you also look into this one https://superuser.com/questions/1335196/ffmpeg-error-when-renaming-batch-files?noredirect=1#comment1996749_1335196